# Resize images to get standard height of a div

Tags: css, image-resizing

hee guys,
I'm trying to get a row with products and resize all images of it, so the height and width of my div won't change.

```
foreach($data['w'] AS $winkeltjes){
if($i %2 == 0){?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">
<?php }?>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="thumbnail shadow">
          <a href="/winkeldetail?w_id=<?php echo $winkeltjes->w_id;?>">
            <?php if($winkeltjes->w_logo != ''){?>
              <img id="maxhoogte" alt="<?php echo $winkeltjes->w_naam.' logo'; ?>" 
              src="/<?php echo $winkeltjes->w_logo;?>/" style=" display: block;">
            <?php }else{?>
              <img id="maxhoogte" alt="<?php echo $winkeltjes->w_naam.' logo'; ?>" 
              src="/images/style/winkeltje.png" style=" display: block;">
            <?php }?>
          </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="product-title">
               <a href="/winkeldetail?w_id=<?php echo $winkeltjes->w_id;?>">
                   <?php echo htmlentities($winkeltjes->w_naam);?>
               </a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="product-price">
                 <?php echo beoordeling($winkeltjes->k_beoordeling);?>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.caption -->
    </div><!--/.thumbnail shadow-->
  </div><!--/.col-xs-6 -->
<?php $i++;
   if($i %2 == 0){?>
   </div><!--/.col-xs-12 col-sm-6 -->
   </div><!--/.row -->
   <?php }
}?>
```

The idea is that all my div's that are created, wont get any bigger so the products will all be in one same line.

my css looks like this:

```
#maxhoogte{
   max-height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail {
   display: block;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   line-height: 1.42857;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img {
     display: block;
     max-height: 100%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto; 
}
.thumbnail .caption {
     padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
     color: #333333; 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: the question you have to ask yourself is 100% of what? no height has been set on the image container (a tag) nor it's container (.thumbnail).

Comment: i want my picture to get maxheight of the  thumbnail > a > img. so the whole row those thumbnails are in, are all equal size to eachother

Comment: I know that @K. Takens, what I am saying is you need to set an actual height on the .thumbnail, like 300px or 5em or whatever, then set height 100% on the a tag so that the max-height on the img will work. When you walk through a doorway you know if you have to duck or not to fit through by being able to see how high the doorway is.

Comment: thanks for your reply! i've set an standard height now, but when i upload a picture at this point, my height's are always equal to the next image, but when it is a landscape photo, the photo is getting ripped appart.

Comment: At this point you need to provide a codepen of what you have so far: http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: i found my problem. I forgot to set a position relative to my parent div and position absolute in my child div. Now i only have to work with @media because i gave my div's some standard height and width.